# How do I create a plus or minus button in my Windows Phone app using XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I want to include a plus or minus button in my Windows Phone app. How can I change the content of the button to plus or minus?

```
<Button x:Name="buttonPlusOrMinus" 
            Content="+/-"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="180,217,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: you can directly add like this.

Comment: <Button Content="+/-"/> what error you are facing?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, What's you problem ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use `±` instead of `+/-`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Exactly that's what I am asking..

Comment: design a image like the +/- as need and set the content of the button as the image. That's how you can get achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this.

- Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key then type 0177 on the numpad and let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd>, this will cause you to type ±.
- Open up the program `charmap` in windows, find the character you are looking for, then click the "Select" then the "Copy" button. You will then be able to paste the ± character in your code.

[image]

- Copy the `±` character from this question into your code.

  ```
  <Button x:Name="buttonPlusOrMinus" 
      Content="±"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="180,217,0,0" 
      Grid.Row="2" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  ```

Comment: The first one didn't work as I don't have numpad but the second one worked like a charm. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the "Accept answer" checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 Dev Icons, Windows store app is the best app to meet all your requirements. You can simply copy and paste to make a + or - button as you want. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-8-dev-icons/9wzdncrdqhbv